# PyQt QWebkit Javascript Function.bind does not exist (ECMAScript 5 missing functions)

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtwebkit, ecmascript-5, qwebkit

Javascript in a web application runs the following loop:

```
    for (var name in this) {
        if(typeof(this[name]) == "function") {
            if((/^on_|^do_/).test(name)) {
        console.debug("Adding ", name, " to ", this, "(", this[name], ")");
                f = this[name].bind;
        console.debug(f);
                this[name] = this[name].bind(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Under Chrome 24.0.1312.56, the line `f = this[name].bind` correctly sets f to the native code `function.bind()`, while in my QWebKit Qt application it sets f to 'undefined'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Any idea how I'd be able to convince QtWebkit to behave correctly here?

---

Apparently, Function.prototype.bind is part of ECMAScript 5. It's implementation in webkit should be covered by (fixed bug): https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26382

Perhaps there is a mode to enable ECMAScript 5 that i'm missing?

---

Apparently i'm using version 534.34 for QtWebkit:

(Pdb) str(QtWebKit.qWebKitVersion())
'534.34'

Which according to this:
https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/85696/trunk/Source/WebKit/mac/Configurations/Version.xcconfig

Corresponds to revision 85696. Combined with the comment in the above bug ("Fixed in r95751"), seems like I need a newer version, specifically anything better than 535.5. Now to find what version of PyQt uses that...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the latest version of PyQt (4.9.6-1) is compiled against wekbit version 534.34.
The first release of webkit that supports Function.prototype.bind is 535.5.

In addition, it seems that both PySite 1.2.2 and PyQt 4.9.6-1 report webkit version 535.34, and do not have Function.prototype.bind.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code which forces you to use `Function.prototype.bind`

```
this[name] = Function.prototype.bind.call(this[name], this)
```

In IE, some of the host objects don't have a bind method on their methods (functions)... could be something related.

Comment: I've tried asking for Function.prototype.bind directly, to which QtWebkit returns undefined. (In the built in dev console)